# Is there any difference between writing meta keywords with or without space?

Tags: seo, html, keywords, meta-tags

Today I was creating keywords for my website and I have one issue.

Is there any difference between writing:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript,PHP"/>
```

And the same code but after every keyword there will be one space like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP"/>
```

I am asking this because when I am surfing the web I usually find both versions. Does it make an impact on website SEO?

Comment: Meta keywords is dead. I recommend that you read some SEO guides written in the last decade :)

Comment: Thats not the answer anyway....I just asked if there is difference

Comment: No. There is no difference. However, @SimonHayter was giving you extremely valuable advice without your realizing it. The keyword meta tag is completely useless. Do not bother with it. As well, I am trying to train people NOT to think in terms of keywords for the simple reason that search engines do not make keyword matches. They makes topical matches and whole sentences, paragraphs, and structure are more important than single terms.

Comment: There is no advantage to having Meta Keywords at all. It's a good sign you've been contacted by a Cargo Cult SEO specialist when they get all het up about you not having any. Nobody who's been overenthusiastic about promoting adding them has been able to ever tell me of any search engine that actually uses them. They're as trustworthy as user submitted content.

Comment: bad info here - the chinese and russian search engines still look at keywords.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In HTML5, [**`keywords`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-keywords) is one of the [standard metadata names](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names).

It defines steps that user agents must follow to obtain the page’s list of keywords. One of these steps is:

> [Split the value of the element's `content` attribute on commas](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#split-a-string-on-commas).

As the linked definition of "split a string on commas" explains, "leading and trailing whitespace" will be stripped:

> [Strip leading and trailing whitespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#strip-leading-and-trailing-whitespace) from *s*.

**tl;dr:** It doesn’t matter if there is a space after or before the delimiter ([i.e., the comma `,`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15954270/1591669)), conforming user agents will obtain the same list of keywords.